# How to add "Syntaxhighlight button" on mediawiki toolbar of WikiEditor?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki

I use mediakiwi to manage documents with my team for a long time.
However, making tags like this is somewhat lengthy and requires many typing:

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="python>
.
</syntaxhighlight>
```

How can I add a template within the WikiEditor just like "gallery tag"?

I could not try anything

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight/VisualEditor